# Pre-allocating memory for linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

In a technical interview, the guy asked me that "he wants to pre-allocate memory for a linked list just like we can do for array", so how would he do that? 
I have never felt the need to, neither came across this thought! I mostly code in C++, and I answered something like "just like we use the new command in C++ for memory allocation, example `int *p = new int[10]` ,where I can allocate 40 bytes of memory, I'd do something same for my Linked List, like  `Node *p = new Node()[10]` , where Node is my Linked List class name, which is like this:

```
class Node{
 public:
  int data;
  Node *next;
};
```

".
Then he further followed it up with how would you go about implementing this and would it really save time, considering space is not an issue? I mainly fumbled my way through the answer and he moved on the next question. 
But I'd really like to know now if I was correct and a small example of it's working/operation would really help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interview questions are generally asked not to be answered directly, and it is expected that you narrow down the use-case and requirements.

> he wants to pre-allocate memory for a linked list just like we can do for array

If that is actually the question, then the interviewer either intentionally asked it wrong or misleading. And array (`std::array` or c-style array) will not only allocate the memory for the types they store but also construct them (at least for non-primitives) so it is important to know if it is a general-purpose list or a specialist list for certain types. A `std::vector`, on the other hand, actually pre-allocates memory.

You generally want to minimize the number of individual memory allocations because those can be expensive.

> I'd do something same for my Linked List, like Node *p = new Node()[10]

You don't want to do that because this would already construct the type managed by the list for each node. In the case of primitives, this won't be much of a problem, but would horribly fail for a general-purpose list like `std::list`.

> Then he further followed it up with how would you go about implementing this and would it really save time, considering space is not an issue?

You would allocate a larger chunk of memory (similar to what `std::vector` does), and when an element is stored in the list, you will use [`placment new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new), to construct the node in the already pre-allocated space.

If space is not a problem and a list would pre-allocate space for, e.g. 100 elements, it would save 99 memory allocations per 100 stored objects. You surely need to add some cost for manually keeping track of which parts of the pre-allocated spaces are free and which one is not, but that is likely to be cheaper than allocating memory.

This is just a rough idea about pre-allocating memory for a list. But the question is missing too many pieces of information to answer it in a meaningful full way.

Answer (score 1):

> how would you go about implementing this

We sure can create nodes without actually storing data in it. We can use a constructor (of the linked list) to get it done.

```cpp
class LinkedList {
public:
    LinkedList(int n)
    {
        pRootNode = new Node();
        Node* pTraveler = pRootNode;

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            pTraveler->next = new Node();
            pTraveler = pTraveler->next;
        }
    }
```

> I'd do something same for my Linked List, like Node *p = new Node()[10]

This will give you an array of nodes. You further need to process it so that the previous node contains the pointer to the next.

> would it really save time

A linked list like this will improve insertions as we don't need to allocate new nodes (until a new node is needed) when inserting a new entry. But instantiation of the linked list will take a small time (comparatively) as we are allocating nodes in the constructor.

Linked lists are said to have `O(1)` insertions and deletions with a worst case of `O(n)` access/ lookup time. So in my opinion, pre-allocating will have little effect because you'll anyway spend an equal amount of time allocating nodes.